# Nextcloud error while setting up on raspberry pi 2

Tags: raspberry-pi, mariadb, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, nextcloud

I successfully installed the latest Raspberry pi OS aka Raspbian on my old pi (server edition) connected it via SSH using my laptop (headless setup) I am semi NOOB in Linux and followed this https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-nextcloud-server/
I am also not familiar with stack overflow, installed Apache2, PHP, nextcloud as in the link now when I go to my IP address/nextcloud nextcloud pages is shown but it shows error
" Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' "
The error code changes I tried all methord possible like droping user and creating it again doing it from 1 and I also noted when I go to http://localhost it dosent work and also found many users with same problem but it was hard to follow but follwed some and edded u in only change in error code
I am semi-noob, I know basic stuff and familiar with terminal but not an expert

Comment: Here is a screenshot for you check, I cloud also go the sampage via http://raspberrypi.local/nextcloud

Comment: screenshot link https://prnt.sc/v98uf9

Comment: I also found when going to the IP address of pi it shows the default Apache " It works" page and IP-address/nextcloud goes to Nextcloud login, I had been doing it from installing Raspbian and all step for 2 times and there was no use : /

Comment: link for users who said to have same problem

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/NextCloud/comments/fzk7se/error_while_trying_to_create_admin_user_failed_to/  https://help.nextcloud.com/t/nextcloud-installation-error-while-trying-to-create-admin-user/20775  https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/issues/1403        THere are many like this but Its hard for me to understand